# Deploying Rails 7 app on Elastic Beanstalks Fails with Nokogiri Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to deploy a Rails 7 app (Ruby 3.0.4) to Elastic Beanstalk which uses Amazon Linux 2.  Possibly could be an issue with installing dependencies for nokogiri?

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.13.7-x86_64-linux in any of the sources
```

> 2022/07/17 13:57:15.371714 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution
> of command [app-deploy] - [stage ruby application]. Stop running the
> command. **Error: install dependencies in Gemfile failed** with **error
> Command /bin/sh -c bundle *2.3.15* install --local failed** with error
> exit status 7. Stderr:Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for
> sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break
> this application for all non-root users on this machine. Could not
> find nokogiri-1.13.7-x86_64-linux in any of the sources

I'm using Bundler 2.3.18 on my mac, I see Elastic Beanstalk is using Bundler 2.3.15, I'm not sure if that will cause issues?

I tried removing all my gems and reinstalling, then deploying to AWS EB.

1. I deleted gemfile.lock
2. I commented out the Gemfile and ran `bundle clean --force` then uncommented the Gemfile afterwards.
3. `rm -rf vendor/cache` to remove cached gems
4. ran `bundle` (re-installed gems again)

Initially I couldn't use bin/dev due to a foreman error so I reinstalled foreman with `rbenv local 3.0.4 && gem install foreman`

After reading https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html I ran `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

I tried this a fallback solution https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#solution_1

```
rm -rf vendor/cache
bundle config set force_ruby_platform true
bundle install
```

I will get an error about the pg gem if I don't cache the gem files under vendor/cache

```
bundle package --all
```

in my gemfile.lock I see the x86_64-linux entries.

```
PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86_64-linux
```

and

```
nokogiri (1.13.7)
  mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.0)
  racc (~> 1.4)
nokogiri (1.13.7-x86_64-linux)
  racc (~> 1.4)
pg (1.4.1)
```

I have a `.ebextensions/options.config` file with the below.  I tried what was in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963315/nokogiri-installation-failes-on-elastic-beanstalk) but it didn't work for me.

```
packages:
  yum:
    amazon-linux-extras: []
    git: []
    patch: []
    gcc: []
    libxml2: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    libxslt: []
    libxslt-devel: []

commands:
  01_A:
    command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql13
  02_B:
    command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
```

At the elastic beanstalk CLI I ran:

```
eb create staging-env -db.engine postgres --database.instance db.t3.micro  --database.username my_user --database.password my_pass --database.size 5 --database.version 13.4 --instance_type t3.micro --single
```

It always fails at the EC2 instance step and the eb-engine.log file will reference nokogiri as the cause.

### **Update**

In cfn-init.cmd.log I'm seeing entries like below which indicate that the dependencies for nokogiri are being installed. Possibly there is a dependency that I missed still?

```
[INFO] yum list installed libxml2
[INFO] Completed successfully.
```

In eb-engine.log the bundle command is being run with the `--local` option by elastic beanstalk.  So it's only looking at `vendor/cache` and the x86_64-linux nokogiri isn't there.

```
error **Command /bin/sh -c bundle _2.3.15_ install --local** failed with error exit status 7. Could not find nokogiri-1.13.7-x86_64-linux in any of the sources
```

I tried passing bundle install in the ebextensions/options.config file but it fails.

```
  04_bundle:
    command: 'bundle install'
```

Comment: I am also having trouble with this today - will let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is what finally ended up working for me.  I created `.ebextensions/ruby.config` with the below package dependencies for nokogiri.

```
packages:
  yum:
    amazon-linux-extras: []
    git: []
    patch: []
    gcc: []
    libxml2: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    libxslt: []
    libxslt-devel: []

commands:
  01_postgresql13:
    command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql13
  02_postgresql-devel:
    command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
```

I ran `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` (there is also an aarch64\arm64 version if you need it) and checked that nokogiri had the new linux version listed in my gemfile.lock

I **deleted all of my cached gems** under `vendor/cache` with `rm -rf vendor/cache`

Make sure everything is committed in git. The important part was to delete the gem cache so that elastic beanstalks bundler doesn't look at the cache and is forced to fetch the linux version of the gem.

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.13.7 (x86_64-linux)
Installing nokogiri 1.13.7 (x86_64-linux)
```